# How to extend wireless network via LAN and not wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

See diagram
[image: diagram]

I have an [Edimax RW-7228apn](http://www.edimax.co.uk/en/produce_detail.php?pd_id=348&pl1_id=1&pl2_id=5) wireless access point. It has LAN IP of 10.0.0.1. I have recently bought a [TP-Link TL-WA830RE Wireless Range Extender](http://uk.tp-link.com/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-WA830RE) to give me extra wireless coverage. I have plugged in the extender but it connects to the AP via wireless. I don't want to do that because the signal is weak. I have ethernet in both wireless locations so want to plug the Extender into ethernet, and give it IP address of 10.0.0.7 to extend the wireless network. Any ideas how to set that up?

In the Edimax it is configured as mode `AP`. Other modes I can choose are:

- Station-Infrastructure
- AP Bridge-Point to point
- AP Bridge-Point to Multipoint
- AP Bridge-WDS
- Universal Repeater

On the TP-Link it is configured as mode `Range Extender Mode 1`. Other options are:

- Access Point
- Range Extender Mode 2

I did think about creating two separate SSIDs and having them both as an AP, but I'd rather just have one SSID for the wireless network. Any advice on what I should do?

Comment: Make them both APs, use the same SSID, use different channels, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up the range extender as an access point. Range extenders want to use the wireless signal as backhaul. If you have a hard-line connection back to your router, then what you have is a network with more than one access point. Looking at the page for your extender, it does have an "AP" mode. What you do is set up each of your wireless access point devices with the same SSID and security information, and you should be able to roam between them without drops. You'll get best results if you use different rf channels, but make sure to only choose from channels 1,6, and 11 in the 2.4Ghz space.

Comment: Channel width (20 or 40 MHz) and Channel has an Auto setting. Should I use that?

Comment: With multiple access points, you'll get better results from the small (20) channel size, to avoid signals to/from various APs stepping on each other's toes. Don't use the Auto setting... it tends to pick unwanted (non-1,6,11) channels.